# ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Tags: postgresql

I have this query :

```
select j.id, j.short_name, j.status
from jobs as j inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
where j.deleted_at is null 
and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
order by case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end, j.short_name;
```

it returns :

```
468883c1-1d3b-420f-b59f-ff71fdbc7a20    GES.PAY DRAFT
468883c1-1d3b-420f-b59f-ff71fdbc7a20    GES.PAY DRAFT
468883c1-1d3b-420f-b59f-ff71fdbc7a20    GES.PAY DRAFT
3404aee7-ff88-47eb-9a51-dc255935384e    CRD.GES.PAY DRAFT
3404aee7-ff88-47eb-9a51-dc255935384e    CRD.GES.PAY DRAFT
3404aee7-ff88-47eb-9a51-dc255935384e    CRD.GES.PAY DRAFT
d2caa1f5-dcaf-4f14-b3f0-bc67d46cc8a3    REL.GES.PAY DRAFT
d2caa1f5-dcaf-4f14-b3f0-bc67d46cc8a3    REL.GES.PAY DRAFT
d2caa1f5-dcaf-4f14-b3f0-bc67d46cc8a3    REL.GES.PAY DRAFT
```

Perfect !

I would like to apply a distinct like that (see the 'distinct' keyword):

```
select distinct j.id, j.short_name, j.status
from jobs as j inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
where j.deleted_at is null 
and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
order by case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end, j.short_name;
```

It returns :

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 5: order by case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 en...
```

I tried a lot of things without success. How can I do this?

Comment: You you want only one row per ID?

Comment: yes , absolutely. Bur the solution I wrote below is fine for me. I think I will adopt it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution like that :

```
select distinct j.id, j.short_name, j.status, case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end
from jobs as j inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
where j.deleted_at is null 
and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
order by case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end, j.short_name;
```

All the columns must appear in the select (it is written in the error message ...). Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

You can put the distinct in a derived table (aka sub-query) and then apply the order by in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct j.id, j.short_name, j.status
  from jobs as j 
    inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
  where j.deleted_at is null 
    and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
)    
order by case 
           when short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 
           else 1 
         end, 
         short_name;
```

If you want to pick on unique id, you can also use `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (j.id) j.id, j.short_name, j.status
from jobs as j 
  inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
where j.deleted_at is null 
  and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
order by j.id, 
         case 
           when short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 
           else 1 
         end, 
         short_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct (j.id, j.short_name, j.status)
from jobs as j inner join job_translations as jt on j.id = jt.job_id 
where j.deleted_at is null 
and short_name ilike '%GES.PAY%' 
order by case when j.short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end, j.short_name;
```

The ORDER BY clause cannot be applied before distinctit can only be applied after the DISTINCT been applied. Only the fields in the SELECT statement are taken into consideration for the DISTINCT operations, those are the only fields may be used in the ORDER BY.

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. Your query returns a **single** column which is an anonymous record type with three fields

Comment: Hi Malik. thanks for your reply. When I added the () , I have the same error message. Your solution does not work...